# Python: Is there a library for 'generator matrices'

Tags: python, matrix, generator, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Dealing with memory issues, I was wondering if there is some library in Python that allows to define a matrix `M` based on some matrix operations, i.e. in a simple case:

```
M = A.dot(B)
```

... or perhaps with some threshold `t`:

```
M = (A.dot(B.T) / C) > t
```

But not actually computes M, **only computes the elements when needed**, i.e. when I ask for `M[i,j]` or `M[i,:]` or `M[[i:j],:]` it computes only those values.

I guess `tensorflow` could be an answer, but I am not sure about that.

Comment: Have you checked `numpy`?

Comment: I guess tf would not help here. Maybe the keyword to look for is *lazy evaluation*. The only thing which comes to (my) mind would be [eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicLazyEvaluation.html), but it's maybe/probably not going far enough

Comment: Hm, "an expression starts to be evaluated once it is assigned to a matrix. Until then nothing happens beyond constructing the abstract expression tree" - sounds like the definition would evaluate the right-hand side?

Comment: Eigen seems to focus on time rather than space...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python lazy evaluation numpy ndarray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923220/python-lazy-evaluation-numpy-ndarray)